# Is the correct type required for the delete operator in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-management, casting

```
void * intptr = new int;
delete (int *) intptr;
```

Is the `(int *)` type cast required?

Comment: possible duplicate of [deleting a buffer through a different type of pointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70880/deleting-a-buffer-through-a-different-type-of-pointer)

Comment: Not a duplicate. That question was asking about using `delete` on something allocated via `new[]` **and** deleting against pointer to a type other than the allocated type. Two invocations of undefined behavior in one statement. Here there is no undefined behavior; the `new` matches the `delete` and the types match as well.

Comment: Note that this is a delete *expression*, not operator. Because there actually is a delete operator (`operator delete`/`operator delete[]`), the distinction is important.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.

The type must match that which was new'd. The only time it doesn't have to match is deletion of a derived type through a base pointer, where the base type has a virtual destructor.

Comment: I was skeptical but found this in the standard: [Note: this
means that the syntax of the delete-expression must match the type of the object allocated by new, not
the syntax of the new-expression. —end note ]

Comment: Just to clarify: The only reason it needs to match isn't so it can be deleted, but so that the correct destructor can be called.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Since C++ is not an everything-is-and-object language, the delete command must know the type of what you want to delete in order to know how to delete it.

Comment: Although that is correct, the comment doesn't make any sense. Anyway I don't see how int or and `int*` is not an object in the C++ sense.

Comment: Compare it to C#. In C#, everything is an object - all data types derive from System.Object, and therefore can share common methods. If C# was not garbage collected, it could have a virtual d'tor in System.Object, enabling it to delete any variable without knowing it's type.
In C++, every reference can be void*, but that doesn't mean void* can contain methods. If everything in C++ was an object, then void* was an object reference, and you could use delete on it(even if it had no virtual d'tor - it would compile and work, it just won't called the d'tor code...)

Comment: @someboddy: Not simple unboxed types though :) So not everything.

Answer (score 1):

> 3 destructors for int will be called.

There's no such thing as a "destructor for int". delete/delete[] will only call a destructor for things that aren't POD or POD-class types.

Answer (score 0):

It is required because delete will call a destructor for each allocated element, even for int.

Consider this:

```
char * chars = new char[3];

delete [] (int*)chars;
```

What will happen? 3 destructors for int will be called. First one for memory address of `&chars[0]`, second one for  `&chars[4]` and third one for `&chars[8]`. Consider that `&chars[4]` and `&chars[8]` exceed the size of allocated memory. Even though `int` destructor in most if not all compilers is dummy it is wrong behaviour. And imagine if you write

```
delete [] (Foo*)chars;
```

where `Foo` has destructor and `sizeof(Foo) > sizeof(char)`. Behaviour of your program will be undefined.