# Deallocating a `char*` with `delete` - memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory, c++11, memory-management

```
template<typename T> char* allocateSomething()
{
    return reinterpret_cast<char*>(std::allocator<T>{}.allocate(1));
}

void deallocateSomething(char* mPtr) { delete mPtr; }

struct TestType { ... };

int main()
{
    char* ptr{allocateSomething<TestType>()};
    deallocateSomething(ptr);   
    return 0;
}
```

Is it guaranteed that `deallocateSomething(ptr)` will free all allocated bytes even if it has no knowledge of the `typename T` used when calling `allocateSomething<T>()`?

Or is it necessary to templatize `deallocateSomething` as well?

EDIT: I manually deal with the construction/destruction of the object.

---

EDIT 2: Will this work correctly?

```
template<typename T> char* allocateSomething()
{
    return reinterpret_cast<char*>(std::malloc(sizeof(T)));
}

void deallocateSomething(char* mPtr) { std::free(mPtr); }

// ...
```

Comment: The value of the pointer is unspecified and deleting an unspecified pointer has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @user2079303: what makes you think it is unspecified ? `char*` is quite special when it comes to dealing with memory.

Comment: @MatthieuM, The standard makes me think so: "The mapping performed by `reinterpret_cast` might, or might not, produce a representation different from the original value." If the standard otherwise guarantees that `reinterpret_cast` to `char*` will not produce a different representation, then I agree that the value may be guaranteed to be well defined.

Comment: @user2079303: That the mapping produces a different value is not a problem, as long as mapping *back* produces the original value. The only requirement to `delete` is that it should operate on the exact pointer that `new` produced; here it might be that this is alright. (Note: I can't find anything that actually substantiate the idea that `char*` to `T*` to `char*` produces the original as long as `T` has a small enough alignment... it must be lurking somewhere in the Standard that I have not checked yet)

Comment: @MatthieuM, Mapping back is guaranteed to work indeed: "Converting a prvalue of type “pointer to T1” to the type “pointer to T2” (where T1 and T2 are object types and where the alignment requirements of T2 are no stricter than those of T1) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value. The result of any other such pointer conversion is unspecified." But I don't see mapping back or `delete` operating on the exact pointer that `new` produced in this code. `new` produces a pointer to `T` and `delete` is called on `char*`.

Comment: Sorry, actually it's `allocator<T>::allocate` which produces the poitner to `T` in this case.

Comment: @user2079303: yes, and `std::allocator::allocate` obtain its storage through `::operator new(size_t)` (directly), however it is unspecified how and when the call occur, which is the heart of the issue here.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I'm not sure what you mean by "(directly") in the comment above, but I don't see that requirement in the standard. The `std::allocator` could get memory from a pool which gets it from `::operator new(size_t)`, or something even more indirect

Comment: -4, really? Didn't think my question was *this* shitty. Sorry.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: I don't quite understand it either...

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I was trying to mean that it did not use a `new` expression (for whatever type, scalar or array form) but instead directly invoked the `::operator new` for raw storage and handled it itself.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo, I can only speculate that people are downvoting for code with undefined behaviour ... which seems unfair when the purpose of the question is to ask if the code is OK.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it guaranteed that deallocateSomething(ptr) will free all allocated bytes even if it has no knowledge of the typename T used when calling allocateSomething()?

No, nothing is guaranteed, it is undefined behaviour.

> Or is it necessary to templatize deallocateSomething as well?

Yes, in general.

You must use matching allocation / deallocation methods. If you want to deallocate with `delete` then you must allocate with `new`.  If you change the allocation so it doesn't use `std::allocator` (which you have no control over and no idea how it allocates) and instead allocates with `new char[sizeof(T)]` then you can  safely deallocate with `delete[]` (but **not `delete`**! You must use the `[]`)

Comment: Will using `std::malloc` and `std::free` instead of a `new/delete` guarantee that the memory will be freed correctly? As far as I know, `malloc` and `free` have no knowledge of types. I deal with construction/destruction manually, so I don't care about that.

Comment: Yes, or matching `new`/`delete` as I explain in my answer. Any matching pair of allocation functions is fine, but you can't mix `malloc` with `free()` or `std::allocator` with `delete`

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: You can indeed use `malloc` and `free`, although using `new[]` and `delete[]` works just as well for `char` (actually, it will likely generate the very same code). You do have to worry about *alignment* though, the generic allocation functions only guarantee an alignment up to `alignof(std::max_align_t)`, so for types that have a greater alignment you may run into issues.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Could you please show me what the correct code would be for the `new[]`/`delete[]` version? Do I have to allocate a `char[]` buffer of size `sizeof(T)`? Thanks.

Comment: @MatthieuM. `new char[]` and `delete []` can be used, but are misleading.  The normal way of obtaining raw memory in C++ would be to call the `operator new()` function, and to call `operator delete` to delete it.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Doubt: where in the standard is it stated that pointer types of `new` and `delete` should match? i.e. `auto *c = new Circle; delete reinterpret_cast<Shape*>(c);` is undefined by which clause? Searched around 5.3.5 in draft n3337, couldn't find anything concrete.

Comment: @legends2k: The values passed to `operator new` and `operator delete` should match, however `new Circle` is not JUST a call to `operator new`, and similarly `delete shape` is not JUST a call to `operator delete`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Right, but I was asking about something else, which seems to have been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591280/is-the-correct-type-required-for-the-delete-operator-in-c#comment9208679_7591297). Anyways, thanks!

Comment: @legends2k do you mean you doubt it's true, or are you asking a question? Assuming the latter, the answer is 5.3.5/3

Answer (score 4):

You have to use matched allocation and free functions.  I.E.

- `malloc` with `free`
- `new` with `delete`
- `new[]` with `delete[]`
- `std::allocator<>::allocate` with `std::allocator<>::deallocate`.  Here the default version is specified to use `new`/`delete`, but it is not specified if it does some grouping of allocations or not (it could below some size and not above for instance), so what you do could work in an implementation, and not in another.