# C++ : deleting different static and dynamic pointer type

Tags: c++

I have a piece of dumb code for which i need some explanations.

```
int main() {
   int *ptr_i = new int[100];
   char *ptr_c = (char *)ptr_i;
   delete [] ptr_c;
   return 0;
}
```

First of all I was expecting this code to crash but it didn't which i believe is because in this case the allocater will keep a track of how many bytes to de-allocate. I ran valgrind also on this code and it shows no memory leak.
I need clarification regarding following :

1. In case when dealing with POD data type, how will a c'tor of char differ from that of int ?
2. Apart from coding convention, what other problems can this code lead to ?

Comment: If it looks like undefined behavior... and walks like undefined behavior...

Comment: Looks like UB to me.  If they were non-pod types then the destructor would never be called.

Comment: "what other problems can this code lead to" Anything. Such is the nature of undefined behavior. Makes this question too broad. Seriously, it is unclear what your actual question is. You know that the code is wrong ("dumb"), so what are you asking? Why does it work anyway? Who knows, it's implementation-dependent, and you don't give us enough information to speculate. Why would the answer even be useful? You should never write code like this.

Comment: Very similar to [deleting a buffer through a different type of pointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70880/deleting-a-buffer-through-a-different-type-of-pointer?rq=1). Just don't!

Comment: its C counterpart should be semantically valid : prt_i = malloc(100*sizeof(int)) ... free(ptr_c) even if symmetry between allocation and desallocation is prefereable for future code review.

Answer (score 5):

There is no constructor for an `int`, nor for a `char`.  However, since the usage of operator `delete` (more accurately `delete []`) does not match the usage of operator `new` (`new []`) the behaviour is undefined.

Undefined behaviour does not mean a crash will occur.  It does not mean that a memory leak will occur.

It simply means that the C++ standard places no restrictions on what happens.

A crash might or might not occur.   A memory leak might or might not occur.   The compiler might or might not reformat your hard drive.   Your program might or might not print the value `42` a total of `27` times.   Any other set of occurrences you can imagine might or might not occur.

So the problems such code may cause could be .... anything  ... or even nothing.   The biggest problem is that you cannot necessarily know.

Comment: As the delete[] invocation is the last thing in the program, even the worst cases of heap corruption and other UB consequences would be very difficult to observe.

Comment: @Lorenzo - Yes, *unless* the UB causes `return 0;` to behave like `system("format C:");`